# Language on SOME sites is stuck on marathi

Tags: languages

If this belongs in another stackexchange, please move it, I couldn't find a better one.

---

Some websites I visit, such an Instagram and Twitter show some of their text in Marathi.

I can't read Marathi, and don't know how to change the language back.

**This issue is not website related**, as it happens on some sites I never even visited before.

It doesn't happen on facebook or google for example.

It only happens on my phone.

It also happened on my previous phone, and keeps haunting me on this one.

I tried all sorts of language changes, and this persists. I don't know what setting to change to get my English back.

I do need Hebrew on my phone as well.

[image: instagram]

Comment: What browser is this? (If stock browser, please also mention the phone model) Also, have you tried other browsers?

Comment: @Andrew.T happens on chrome, and the browser which opens when clicking links in whatsapp or telegram. Does not happen on firefox.

Comment: WhatsApp and Telegram might use Chrome's Custom Tab, so this might be from Chrome's settings instead: [Wrong language in a new Chrome private window and in integrated data](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/189430/44325)

Comment: It looks more like those apps deciding on a language based on your location/IP address. I face it all the time on mobile version of Facebook.

Comment: @andrew.T that was it!.finally it is fixed